# ASP.NET Core 2.2 Authentication not working

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm trying to create my own login authentication, it wasn't working so I create this quick test...

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    try
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Test Name"));
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

        SignIn(principal, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        var isAuthenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;    //-- THIS IS ALWAY FALSE... BUI JUST LOGGED IN?!?!?!?

        return View();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Error:");
        return StatusCode(500);
    }
}
```

So you can see I call `SignIn` then on the next line I check if the user is now authenticated but its always returns false, also the `User.Identity` looks empty. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong here?

In my Startup / ConfigureServices i have:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/Admin/Index";
    });
```

And in Startup / Configure

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
{
    MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> SignIn(principal, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
> ```

This is a no-op. `SignIn` is a convenience method for creating an instance of a `SignInResult` and would usually be returned from an action. This follows the command pattern, but your example just creates the command and never executes it.

What you really want is the following:

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);
```

You can provide the the scheme if you want to, but you've set `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` as the default in `ConfigureServices` so this will be assumed.

However, even with this change, `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` will still be `false` until another request is made. Typically, you'd do something like this:

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);

return RedirectToAction(...);
```

With your setup, calling `SignInAsync` ends up creating a cookie that stores the authentication information. It doesn't update the current `User`. On the next request, caused by the redirect, the cookie is read by your ASP.NET Core app and the `User` is populated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I see your `Index` method missing `Authorize` attribute. Please add `Authorize` attribute as follows:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ....
}
```

Then in the `Configure` method of the `Startup` class the middlewares order should be as follows:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
        ......

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
        {
            MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict,
        });

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
}
```

Now it should work for you.

Comment: No, this doesn't work, if I add [Authorize] to the action you can't access it as i'm not logged on. Normally I would have [Authorize] on all my controllers and actions and not on the action used to authorize.

Comment: Oh! You getting things wrong! Without authorize attribute and logged in `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;` will always be false. That's the expected behavior.

Comment: Here's the thing, I'm not logged in. The code in the action is required to run before I am logged in, but its not working. NOTE: Using the [Authorize] attribute will stop Non logged in users accessing the action: SEE: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Answer (score 0):

Here is sourcecode fo `SignIn`

```
public virtual SignInResult SignIn(
  ClaimsPrincipal principal,
  string authenticationScheme)
=> new SignInResult(authenticationScheme, principal);
```

Above code simply returns an object `SignInResult`, which does nothing action at that moment.

Here is sourcecode of `SignInResult`: 
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/SignInResult.cs

Here is core code:

```
public class SignInResult : ActionResult
{

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        ...
        await context.HttpContext.SignInAsync(AuthenticationScheme, Principal, Properties);
    }
}
```

It is a return type `ActionResult` and it's simply calling `context.HttpContext.SignInAsync`, so `ControllerBase.SignIn` is the sort of shortcut for `HttpContext.SignInAsync()`.

BUT! Take a look the following `ActionResult`:

```
public abstract class ActionResult : IActionResult
{
  public virtual Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
  {
   this.ExecuteResult(context);
   return Task.CompletedTask;
  }

  public virtual void ExecuteResult(ActionContext context)
  {
  }
}
```

So `SignInResult` does nothing on the `Sync` method, but only `Async`.

What I can suggest is:

1. In your test method, you can only `return SignIn(...)`, then the action will be proformed automatically, then you can check if its authorized in next request.
2. if you want to SignIn and do something else in one action, directly use `HttpContext.SignInAsync()`, which is for your current code.
3. [this options is just for fun]Regarding the  `SignInResult` implemented the `async` function only, but does nothing in `sync` method, so you can try to change your test action to `async Task<IActionResult>`